# My site looks the same in FireFox and Google Chrome but not IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

My site looks great in `Firefox`, `Safari`, and `Google Chrome`, But terrible in `IE`. It isn’t properly positioned. Here’s my code and a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/an5jS/)

Code:

```
    .container{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:620px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .box{
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#ccc;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        margin-top:20px;
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .spacing{
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    }
    .banner{
     margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border:4px solid black;
    padding:0px;
    }

     #one{
     opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
     }

     #one:hover{
    opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    }  

    #two{
    opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

        #two:hover{
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

        #three{
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

        #three:hover{
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;

        }

        #four{
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

       #four:hover{
       opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
       }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/y9T3TJq.jpg" class="banner">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="box spacing" id="one"><a href="http://www.reddit.com">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/PVP.png" width="300px" height="300px"></a></div>
            <div class="box spacing"id="two"><a href="http://www.reddit.com">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Kingdoms.png" width="300px" height="300px"></a></div>

                <div class="box spacing"id="three"><a href="http://www.reddit.com">
                <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Survival.png" width="300px" height="300px"></a></div>
                    <div class="box spacing"id="four"><a href="http://www.reddit.com">
                    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Factions.png"  width="300px" height="300px"></a></div>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I’ll update this thread if I find a solution. Thank you for reading!

Comment: it's because IE doesn't do `margin: 0 auto correctly.

Comment: are you facing problem in translation.. coz i check your http://jsfiddle.net/an5jS/ in IE, its not translationing opacity part like in chrome

Comment: This question may be voted close because the statement "It isn’t properly positioned." is not specific enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues.

Firstly you only give the transitions to WebKit browsers as you use the webkit prefix. You need the prefixless version for Firefox, Opera and IE. I'd also include the -moz- prefix for the versions that still need it.

Next you keep repeating the same code for the four boxes. This doesn't create compatibility issues, but isn’t ideal. I've move the code to the box class, as that is only used on the four divs.

Finally, if an image is wrapped in an anchor, IE adds a border to show it is a link. You can remove that via CSS by setting the border to none:

```
a img {
   border: none;
}
```

See a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/an5jS/7/

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/), try using:

```
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:620px;
    text-align: center; /* instead of margin: 0px auto; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer, any image with a Hyperlink will have a blue border... just add border="0" inside the img tag. Example below:

```
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/PVP.png" border="0" width="300px" height="300px">
```